# how to get handle of already attached device in linux kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel

I am new to linux kernel driver.

I would like to know , how I can get the device handle from my own kernel module to an existing device which has already been registered and has a registered driver.

I wanted to create some calls to this driver module in order to call generic APIs for testing the driver.

Comment: You call `open` on the device file.

Comment: Sorry but I am not trying to ask from user space. I need to get device handle from another kernel module which I have implemented for testing the original device driver module.. This kernel module I have created as a character driver

Comment: Why can't you test from user space?

Comment: A bit hackish but you could imagine keeping a list of all the registered devices for this module and export the symbol for this list. That way you can access the list from any other module. Same can be done for all the devices access functions.

Comment: Thanks for inputs !! Thought I have thought of having hack to expose device list but it seems it will not be accepted in main line kernel. I want to test from user space but the kernel driver module doesn't expose any interface/functions to user space in order to test the driver APIs.

Comment: What I was thinking is to create a kernel module which exposes the kernel driver module APIs to user space using "ioctl" interface so for this reason I have  created a "char" driver but the issue is I am not able to directly call the driver APIs and have no clue how to pass device handle to my char driver in such case.

Comment: I searched a lot online and do not know how the linux device driver modules are tested in such case ? I am sure that I need to pass device handle to my driver module but do not know what is the correct way. This kernel driver module is part of device tree and all the initialization is happening in it's probe function. I think this is common model all device drivers are following in the linux kernel.

Comment: What kind of testing do you want to do? Generally device drivers are tested by acting on the hardware directly. The most generic code may be unit-tested by compiling the code to user-land with a wrapper.